# convert list = {"x-y", "w-z", "a-b"} into dict={x:y. w:z,a:b}

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have searched a lot on how to convert list into dictionary and found solutions but none of them have given the solution.

I have a list

```
LIST = {"x-y", "w-z","a-b"}
```

Now i want to convert it into a dictionary which should look like

```
DICT = {'x':'y', 'w':'z', 'a':'b'}
```

Comment: your `LIST` object is not a `list`, but a `set`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When faced with such issues it's always good to think a few things through.

**What is a dictionary?**

A dictionary is conceptually a key-value storage meaning each *element* in a dictionary is a pair of `(key, value)`. We can assign values to a dictionary using `d[key] = value` and we can retrieve a value using `d[key]`.

Now we know how we can put values into a dictionary.

**What's the format of my input data?**
and **What do I need to do to convert my input data?**

Or input format is `<key>-<value>` which means we can use `split` to 
extract the key and value.

```
>>> "x-y".split("-")
['x', 'y']
```

This allows us to do this:

```
DICT = {}
for element in LIST:
    parts = element.split("-")

    if len(parts) != 2:
          # handle this case? (see below)
          ...

    (key, value) = (parts[0], parts[1])
    DICT[key] = value
```

**What do I do on errors?**

Can my input format contain `x-y-a`. What is this? Is this `(x-y,a)` or is it `(x,y-a)`? Or is it illegal? How do I deal with `-`? How do I deal if there's no `-` in it? I.e.

```
>>> dict(x.split('-', 1) for x in ["a"])
```

Would throw an exception that you might want to handle if you use this approach:

```
>>> dict(x.split('-', 1) for x in ["a"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

`dict(x.split('-', 1) for x in` only works for correctly formated inputs for example.

**Are there other ways to construct a dictionary?**

Reading through the documentation you'll find that there's `dict` that takes a list of 2-tuples. Which means you can do this:

```
>>> dict([('a','b'),('c','d')])
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
input = {"x-y", "w-z","a-b"} 
output = dict(x.split('-', 1) for x in input)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {x.split('-')[0]: x.split('-')[1] for x in LIST}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dict`

**Ex:**

```
l = {"x-y", "w-z","a-b"}
print( dict([i.split("-") for i in l]) )
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': 'b', 'x': 'y', 'w': 'z'}
```

Note: `l` is a `set` not a list

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {}                //simple dictionary declaration
for i in LIST:        // for loop to iterate and access each element of LIST
    d[i[0]] = i[2]    // this will use 1st letter of each word as key and 3rd letter as value of dictionary
```

Comment: i variable will iterate through values of LIST like "x-y". Now i[0] i.e. x, which will become key and i[2] i.e. y will be its value.Similar for all values in LIST and after loop, the value of d will be {"x":"y","a":"b","w":"z"}

Comment: Please edit your answer and explain your code there. Code in comments is hard to read.